# flutter xcode build/archive fails but can run from terminal

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I'm having issues with publishing flutter app to ios.

When I run `flutter build ios` my app builds, if I run it using `flutter run` it also builds and starts the app. But when I try to run it using xcode or archive it I get errors. There are two kind of them:

```
open flutter/packages/integration_test/ios/Classes/FLTIntegrationTestRunner.h: Operation not permitted
```

or

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I did try to add `-f` to -frameworks.sh. Not sure what is the problem.

Xcode version: 14.3.1
Flutter version: 3.10.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about your apple connect account? Did you add it to xcode accounts? also check @Next day Software answer, apple changed relative path to absolute path and you need change some lines of code to force the path.

Comment: It is logged in, I have checked it twice. I worked before..

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this link and change the source as given in it. It worked for me to create the archive. This is the bug from upgrading the xcode from 14.2 to 14.3. Hope this helps to you to archive your project.
worked for me!  in APPNAME/ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh replaced source="$(readlink "${source}")" with source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"

> https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727493

Comment: As I said I did try that already.